# How can install scripts determine which are the correct equivalents for /usr/lib for 32- and 64-bit libraries?

Tags: linux, installation, 32bit-64bit, libraries

I have an SDK that must install 32-bit and 64-bit files in the correct places under /usr/lib
for a variety of Linux distributions.

For example, it appears that for Fedora, /usr/lib64 is the 64bit lib, but for Debian based systems, /usr/lib is the 64bit directory.

I want to find out if there is a reliable way to determine the correct locations.

More specifically, is there a way an install script can determine programmatically which are the correct equivalents for /usr/lib for 32- and 64-bit libraries on a given distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my ubuntu server, I have the path `/usr/lib64/` points to the path `/usr/lib/`. As it is known ubuntu is a debian-based system. So, you can install the 64-bit libs in /usr/lib64 for both fedora and ubuntu.

Also, have a look at [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html). They are recommending installing the libs in `/usr/local/lib`.

```
The GNU standards recommend installing by default all libraries in /usr/local/lib when distributing source code (and all commands should go into /usr/local/bin).
They also define the convention for overriding these defaults and for invoking the installation routines.
```

You have to make sure that your libs path is included in the ldconfig configuration files.

Comment: While it looks like placing 64-bit libraries into /usr/lib64 will work, yet some questions remain.

Where should the 32-bit libraries be installed for popular Linux distributions? 

Are there are circumstances where installing 64-bit libraries into /usr/lib64 will not work?

In summary, I was hoping there is a reliable way that works for all popular distributions.

Comment: Did you try it and it did not work!?

Comment: Using the information you provided a successful solution was implemented, thanks.

Comment: I am glad to here this :)